# How to solve the system of equations $\{10^{-4}x_1+x_2=1, x_1+x_2=2\}$ using finite precision arithmetic with three significant figures?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

> Consider the following two equations:
>
> $10^{-4}x_1+x_2=1$
>   $x_1+x_2=2$
>
> Solve using Gaussian Elimination using finite precision arithmetic with three significant figures.

I'm a little stuck understanding finite precision arithmetic.  Does this mean that I rewrite this as follows:

$0.1\times10^{-3}x_1+.1\times 10 x_2=.1\times 10$
$.1\times 10x_1+.1\times 10 x_2=.2\times 10$

Or, do I compute this as I normally would and round off at the end.

Comment: $10^{-4}=0$ in this arithmetic; solution is $x_1=x_2=1$.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Leading zeros are not counted. $10^{-4}$ should stay as it is.

Comment: @abet: To answer your question, NO. You should work on the system written on top of your question. Finite digit approximation will not take part at the first step (why?). Just use the Naive Gaussian elimination (no pivoting), and ROUND THE NUMBERS AFTER EACH STEP OF COMPUTATION. For example, round after finding the multiplier, and after multiplying it by the first row, and after adding this result to the second row, etc.

Comment: @Meshal, ok, but in this case you can solve this system in a usual way: multiply first equation by $10^4$ etc. At the end round $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple response is to solve the problem as stated:  $$\begin {pmatrix}10^{-4}&1\\1&1 \end {pmatrix} \begin {pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end {pmatrix}$$ but at each step of the solution to throw away any significant figures more than $3$  As you only have $3$ significant figures, the $10^{-4}$ tends to get lost.  It is instructive to solve the system exactly, getting $$\begin {pmatrix}10^{-4}&1\\1-10^{-4}&0 \end {pmatrix} \begin {pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end {pmatrix}\\x_1=\frac 1{1-10^{-4}}\approx 1\\x_2=1-\frac {10^{-4}}{1-10^{-4}}\approx 1$$ and the $10^{-4}$ term doesn't matter at all.

I would have expected the coefficient matrix to be almost singular.  Then the computed values can be badly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solveing this exactly,
$x_1(1-.0001) = 1$
so
$x_1
=\frac1{.9999}
$
and
$x_2
=2-x_1
=2-\frac1{.9999}
=\frac{2*.9999-1}{.9999}
=1-\frac{.0001}{.9999}
$.

Rounding to 3 places,
$x_1 = 1$
and
$x_2 = 1$.